# Move an Object (OpenGL)

Tags: c++, object, move

I'm doing a program in C++ using OpenGL.

My game have a ship and enemy ships.

At the moment i can move my ship as i'm pleased with my keyboard.

But I would love to give some move to my enemy ships. For example, they are located in certain coordinates x, y and i would like to have a method that would move them 5 steps right, 5 steps left repetitively in a certain amount of time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `void glutTimerFunc(unsigned int msecs,void (*func)(int value), value);`
First parameter is time in msec, second parameter is function where you update the co-ordinate of the enemy ships. Details description you can find [here.](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node64.html) You can see the below how to use it.

```
void update(int value) {
//do your logic to change the cordinate of the enemy ships
glutPostRedisplay();
glutTimerFunc(25, update, 0);
}
```

This is the function name update where you put the logic to change the co-ordinate of the enemy ships. Inside it you saw glutTimerFunc where time is 25 msecs its means function update is called in every 25 msecs and co-ordinates of enemy ships changes according to your logic. You have to call the glutTimerFunc in main function.

```
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
 //your program code
  glutTimerFunc(25, update, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called velocity, and user input should change the velocity.

If you have a position, `X` and you have a velocity `vx` (velocity in x) after a certain amount of time, `t` you will get a a new position `X'` by `X'=X+vx*t`

Simply call something like

```
void update()
{
    myObject.X += myObject.vx*t;
}
void leftArrow()
{
    const float increment = 0.05f;
    const float maxSpeed = 0.50f;
    if (myObject.vx >= maxSpeed)
    {
        myObject.vx -=increment;
    }
}
```

How do you choose `t`?
In the case of the smooth motion you describe, virtually any small value of `t` will work. If you plan on having more complicated motion, such as collisions you will need to evaluate the stability of the functions you are integrating... (although that is way beyond what you described.)

Comment: But how do i determine t? which is my time variable

Comment: @user2139338 the only way to find t is experimentally. Once you find it, make sure everything in your game uses the same t.

Answer (score 0):

To move a ship from *A* to *B* in *δt* seconds (starting at *t<sub>0</sub>*), you simply draw it at *A* + (*B* - *A*)(*t* - *t<sub>0</sub>*)/*δt* (where *t* is the current time) on each frame until *t* = *t<sub>0</sub>* + *δt*.

Note that this induces linear motion. If you want to speed up and slow down at the start and finish of the movement, that's more complicated. To smooth it out without getting all caught up in physics, you could use the [Smoothstep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep) function, replacing (*t* - *t<sub>0</sub>*)/*δt* with smoothstep(*t<sub>0</sub>*, *t<sub>0</sub>* + *δt*, *t*).